# Security.Authenticator is not working in Junit test

Tags: java, spring, junit, playframework-2.0

I am writing the `junit` Test for the `controllers` in `JavaPlay framework`. I used `Spring Security` for login authentication. [Here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaGuide4) is the source I used for reference. Everythings is working fine until I start writing test cases for the controller. The issue is unit test shows weird behaviour.

Here is the test file:

```
@Test
public void loginTestFail(){
    Result result = invokeWithContext(fakeRequest("GET","/merchantVisibility"), () ->
            assetController.merchantVisibilityDemo());
    Assert.assertEquals(303,result.status());
    Assert.assertEquals("/login",result.header("Location"));
}

@Test
public void loginTest(){
    Map map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("email","abc@xyz.com");
    Result result = invokeWithContext(fakeRequest("GET","/merchantVisibility").session(map), () ->
            assetController.merchantVisibilityDemo());
    Assert.assertEquals(200,result.status());
}
```

Here is the controller file:

```
@Singleton
@Security.Authenticated(LoginAuthAction.class)
public class AssetController extends Controller {
    private static Logger.ALogger logger = LogUtil.getLogger(AssetController.class);

    public Result merchantVisibilityDemo() {
        File file = new File(Play.current().path().toString() + "/public/html/merchant_visibility.html");
        logger.debug(session().get("email"));
        return ok((file));
    }
}
```

Here is the LoginAuthAction Class :

```
public class LoginAuthAction extends Security.Authenticator {
private String SESSION_TIMEOUT = "sessionTimeout";
private final Configuration configuration;
private static Logger.ALogger logger = LogUtil.getLogger(LoginAuthAction.class);

@Inject
public LoginAuthAction(Configuration configuration) {
    this.configuration = configuration;
}

@Override
public String getUsername(Http.Context ctx) {
    logger.debug(ctx.session().get("email"));
    //see if user is logged in
    if(ctx.session().get("email") == null){
        return null;
    }

    // see if session expires
    String prevTime = ctx.session().get("userTime");
    if(prevTime != null && !prevTime.equals("")){
        long prevT = Long.valueOf(prevTime);
        long currentT = new Date().getTime();
        long timeout = Long.valueOf(configuration.getLong(SESSION_TIMEOUT))*60*1000;
        if(currentT - prevT > timeout){
            ctx.session().clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    String tickString = Long.toString(new Date().getTime());
    ctx.session().put("userTime",tickString);
    return ctx.session().get("email");
}

@Override
public Result onUnauthorized(Http.Context ctx) {
    return redirect(controllers.routes.AuthenticationController.login(ctx.request().path().toString()));

}
```

This is the error I got :

```
[error] Test controllers.AssetControllerTest.loginTestFail failed: expected:<303> but was:<200>, took 4.427 sec
```

The problem is that the code flow does not enter the `LoginAuthAction` Class.

How do I overcome this error ?

When I am running the App in the Browser the flow works fine but having this problem in testing.